# Undefined referece to Function for OpenSSl app in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openssl

Hi am new to eclipse IDE and OpenSSL . It shows the error called cannot open lib files and Undefined referece to (Function). Can anybody give me suggestion for  adding the correct path for the application  am trying from last few days am stuck with it.......

the error look like this Build Error

Build of configuration Debug for project R&D **

Internal Builder is used for build               **
gcc -LD:\source codes\openssl\lib -oR&D.exe openssl\applink.o main.o
main.o: In function `main':
D:\c&c++programs\R&D\Debug/../main.c:53: undefined reference to`RAND_pseudo_bytes'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 331  ms.

one more thing am using the MinGW as my compiler for Eclipse.It is a C & C++ application

Comment: It shows that error doing what? Can you show us the offending code that is causing that error? Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Sounds like a linker error, but like Selcuk said, no one can help unless you post the exact error Eclipse threw at you.

Comment: i added the build error message from the eclipse ide.... Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... am new to eclipse IDE and OpenSSL...

You must add OpenSSL to the project.

First, OpenSSL includes must be added:

[image]

Second, the OpenSSL libraries must be added:

[image]

Comment: i have no issue to setup openssl on Ubuntu Eclipse, but fails on Windows Eclipse. How to setup openssl (1.1.1i) on Windows Eclipse?